# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the entire sub-array from **arr** if any of the items equal to **elem**.

Here's the code

```
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
         if (arr[i][j] === elem) {
           arr.splice(i, 1);
         }
       }
    }
    return newArr = [...arr];
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
```

If I remove the condition in the IF statement, the error disappears. Why is the condition in the If statement causing the error?

I'm trying to understand why the error is coming up so that I will not repeat it again

Answer (score 1):

Just use `filter` and check with `includes` if the `subArray` contain the `elem`

```js
function filteredArray(arr, elem) {
   return arr.filter(subArr => !subArr.includes(elem))
}

console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [3, 13, 26], [19, 3, 9]], 3));
console.log(filteredArray([[3, 2, 3], [1, 6, 3], [2, 13, 26], [19, 4, 9]], 3));
```